# Saving XML file content to String or StringBuilder

Tags: c#

I want to save The whole content of XML file to a string or stringbuilder. Please let me know how can i achive that??

My Function needs to copy or Save a XML file content Completely to string or stringbuilder.
It is External Content(XML File).After that I need to change the Content(onf field ) of the xml file Can i achive it through C#. please let me know.

I Have following content in XML format , i want to put into one string and pass that to another Function in order to achive my Work.

---

```
        <wsa:Address xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
        <wsa:ReferenceParameters xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsman="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd">
        <wsman:ResourceURI>http://schema.unisys.com/wbem/wscim/1/cim-          </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
        </p:Source>
     </p:INPUT>";
```

--------------------------------------------------

Regards,
Channaa

Comment: What have you tried? Opening a file and getting all its contents is one of the most fundamental operations...

Comment: Why do you need to store entire XML file in a string ? `Is the question like - Reading the XML file, changing element / attribute and saving it back ?`. If yes, then there are enormous amount of samples available. Just search it on. Something like `XDocument.Load(@"C:\MyFile.xml");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

// load the file
            var xDocument = XDocument.Load(@"C:\MyFile.xml");
// convert the xml into string (did not get why do you want to do this)
            string xml = xDocument.ToString();
```

Now, using [xDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx), you can manipulate the XML & save it back -

```
           xDocument.Save(@"C:\MyFile.xml");
```

Answer (score 7):

Reading an XML file into a string is simple:

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

The to access the content, you would read it into an XmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly read XML to [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(xmlFilePath);
```

When you need XML as string then use [XmlNode.OuterXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx) property.